# Issue related to Kafka Transaction

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have written a Kafka Consumer and Producer. The producer is a transacted producer and the consumer is configured with isolation.level as read_commited.

But eventually, after sometime, the consumer is not able to read the data. It does not happen suddenly. It happens eventually.

When i checked, i found that the LSO (lastStableOffset) associated with read_commited consumer is not getting updated even after the transaction is completed at producer side. It is still being the start index of the transacted message.

If anyone got any idea on this, please guide me through. However, i am using a 3 node cluster kafka setup with version 2.3.0. The following are some properties which i specify in the server.properties of the Kafka broker.

- default.replication.factor=3
- min.insync.replicas=2
- offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
- transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
- transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
- offsets.retention.minutes=10080
- transaction.max.timeout.ms=18000000
- num.partitions=2
- log.retention.hours=24

When i tried changing the KafkaConsumer to read_uncommited mode, it started reading the message since it no longer depends on lastStableOffset. So, i believe it has some connections related to updation of lastStableOffset.

Comment: did you check the isr for your topic, are all matching the min.isr?, any replication issues you can find in the brokers logs?

Comment: Yes. I tried describing my topic and i can see the the ISR is all met accordingly to what set in server.properties. I believe that it is not related to replication.